# How can I run Tiberian Sun on Windows 7?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun

I downloaded EA's [free *Command & Conquer: Tiberian Sun*](http://www.commandandconquer.com/classic) release, but when I try to run it, it complains of missing or broken DLLs. I tried to run the DLL regfix file, but it errored saying it could not access the registry. What do I do to fix it? I don't think the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10353/running-command-conquer-gold-on-windows-7-64-bit-in-xp-mode) would help (I don't think what I have is *Command and Conquer Gold*).

Comment: Have you got Windows 7 professional and therefore the "XP Mode" virtual machine? You could try installing it there instead...

Comment: @Graham: I think I do, but i'm currently borrowing a friends machine and i'm trying to stay "low impact" :)

Comment: @GrahamClark, it wouldn't work in the XP Mode virtual machine. It doesn't support any 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 5):

Right click and run as administrator, but be aware the game is not compatible with 64 bit versions of Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

Run in Windows XP compatibility mode, then it'll work on Windows 7 64bit. I tested it, and it worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try 3d analyzer, lower the resolution and then try changing the compatibility from Windows 7 to XP.